# Find values in list and increment country count

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of email addresses and countries on one tab, eg below.

```
| Email                     | Country        |
| -----                     | -------        |
| user@domain.com           | United States  |
| anotheruser@domain.com    | United Kingdom |
| yetanotheruser@domain.com | United States  |
| user3@domain.com          | France         |
```

I want to paste a list of email addresses in another tab to be compared to the list above and where the email address from the second tab is found in the first table, have a count on countries on another tab, for example.

```
| Country        | Count |
| -------        | ----- |
| United States  | 2     |
| United Kingdom | 1     |
| France         | 1     |
```

I hope this makes sense. How would you go about it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the first table is on `sheet1` and you want to show the 2nd table in `sheet2`.
For instance, if we want to find the frequency of `"United States"` in tab 2 which is sheet2, 
 `=COUNTIF(sheet1!B1:B10,"United States")`

[image]

Comment: Only where the email address is matched from a separate list. I want to paste a list of email addresses in another tab, and the country count increments against the email matches.

Comment: i think, firstly you want to check the email address is valid or not based on another list then increment the country count, is it? if possible show all the list and the output you want.